# Directly access members of members in a class interface without inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++14, member

The problem that I am facing is that in my application it matters in which order the members of my class are initialized in the constructor. And thus I need to use clumsy syntax to get the behaviour I am aiming for.

This should outline my problem (see below code): I want my `class Widget` to include the interface of `class WidgetSignals` from the user's point of view. I can't use inheritance because that requires me to initialize the inherited `WidgetSignals` before the member `elements` of the `Widget` which should be used to initialize `WidgetSignals`.

```
template<typename... Elems>
class WidgetSignals
{
    WidgetSignals(const std::tuple<Elems...> elems)
        : // initialize members using elems
    {}
    // members ...
};

template<typename... Elems>
class Widget : public WidgetSignals<Elems...>
{
    std::tuple<Elems...> elements;

    Widget(vec4 quad)
        : WidgetSignals<Elems...>(elements) // uh-oh! elements are not initialized yet!
        , elements(initalizeElements(quad))
};
```

Here are my previous solutions to this problem:

Use a mediator helper class:

```
template<typename... Elems>
class Widget : public WidgetSignals<Elems...>
{
    std::tuple<Elems...> elements;

    struct Data
    {
        Data(vec4 quad)
            : elems(initializeElements(quad))  // initialize elements here
        {}        
        std::tuple<Elems...> elems;
    };
    Widget(Data data)
        : WidgetSignals<Elems...>(data.elems) // bingo!
        , elements(data.elems)
    {}
};
```

Encapsulate `WidgetSignals` and expose references to `WidgetSignals`' members in Widget:

```
template<typename... Elems>
class Widget
{
    std::tuple<Elems...> elements;
    WidgetSignals<Elems...> signals;

    Widget(vec4 quad)
        : elements(initializeElements(quad))
        , signals(elements) // initialized after elements because of order of member declaration
    {}
    // WidgetSignal member references
    const typename WidgetSignals<Elems...>::SignalType& enter = signals.enter;
    const typename WidgetSignals<Elems...>::SignalType& leave = signals.leave;
    // ... remaining members
};
```

With both of these solutions I can then use the interface of `WidgetSignals` through a `Widget`:

```
Widget widget(vec4(0, 0, 20, 5));
foo(widget.enter);
```

But both of these solution are rather hacky and messy, so I would really like to have a better syntax for this, something like:

```
using signals;
```

or

```
using signals::enter;
```

in `Widget`. `using WidgetSignals<Elems...>::enter;` is actually something that works, but only if `Widget` already inherits from `WidgetSignals` and that would mean I had to use a mediator helper class again, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: `class Widget : private ElementsWrapper, public WidgetSignals<Elems...>`, and move `elements` into `ElementsWrapper`. This effectively flips the order of initialization.

Comment: How do you expect to use the `WidgetSignals` class if you don't initialise an instance of it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hey thanks, that was just as simple as I needed it to be. I should get some sleep though.

Comment: @Peter an instance of it is being initialized in the constructor of `Widget`. Either as a base class or as the member variable `signals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stick the elements you want to initialise first into a [`private`] base class you inherit from first. For example:

```
template<typename... Elems>
struct WidgetPbase {
    std::tuple<Elems...> elements;
}
template<typename... Elems>
class Widget
    : private WidgetPbase<Elems...>
    , public WidgetSignals<Elems...>
{
public:
    Widget(vec4 quad)
        : WidgetPbase<Elems...>{initializeElements(quad)}
        , WidgetSignals<Elems...>(elements) {
    }
};
```

As base classes as inherited left-to-right/top-to-bottom this arranges for the `elements` member to be initialised at the point it is accessed. The only potential caveat is that `virtual` bases are initialised first: if `WdigetSignals` is a `virtual` base it may be necessary to stick a `virtual` in front of `WidgetPbase`.